# How can I add a border INSIDE this element?

Tags: border, css

How can I add a `1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6)` border, `5px` *inside* the following `fieldset`?

Result should be something like this:

[image: a]

I only need this to be compatible with Chrome latest, Firefox latest, and IE 9.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dFDw6/), and my current code:

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>&nbsp;</fieldset>
```

**CSS**

```
fieldset
{
    background: #3AA0BD;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3AA0BD 0%, #06446E 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3AA0BD), color-stop(100%,#06446E));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3AA0BD 0%,#06446E 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3AA0BD 0%,#06446E 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3AA0BD 0%,#06446E 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3AA0BD 0%,#06446E 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3AA0BD', endColorstr='#06446E',GradientType=0 );
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    /* temp */
    height: 60px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

The height and width are unknown. I've just added them here to fill out the `fieldset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a wrapping element? ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuEGF/))

***Edited by OP:*** This is what I ended up doing, since I already had a `form` element 'wrapping' the `fieldset`:

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <fieldset>&nbsp;</fieldset>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form
{
    background: #3AA0BD;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3AA0BD 0%, #06446E 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3AA0BD), color-stop(100%,#06446E));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3AA0BD 0%,#06446E 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3AA0BD 0%,#06446E 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3AA0BD 0%,#06446E 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3AA0BD 0%,#06446E 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3AA0BD', endColorstr='#06446E',GradientType=0 );
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

fieldset
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Since I already had the `<fieldset>` wrapped in a `<form>`, I just used the `<form>` as the wrapper. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

With normal CSS I don't think there is a inline CSS rule for this. You got `box-shadow` with an inline part, but this won't work in every browser.

Please see this following URL: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-multiple-borders-with-simple-css/

Where you can use `:before` and `:after` to create another element inside and `position absolute` it so the whole content is selected minus the width and height of the border.

```
    #box {  
        background: #f4f4f4;  
        border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;  
        width: 200px;  
        height: 200px;  
        margin: 60px auto;  
        position: relative;  
    }  
    #box:before {  
        border: 1px solid white;  
        content: '';  
        width: 198px;  
        height: 198px;  
        position: absolute;  
    }  
    #box:after {  
        content: '';  
        position: absolute;  
        width: 196px;  
        height: 196px;  
        border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;  
        left: 1px; top: 1px;  
    }
```

Comment: +1 for using a pseudo element. This should be the correct answer IMO.